# Iterate a huge list of integers which grow exponentially, where the exponent is 1.5

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to iterate a list of integers:

```
2, 3, 4, 6, 9, 13, 19, 28, 42, ...
```

So the general rule is `list[i+1] = list[i]*3/2`.

The list should end at or right before 10^34.

This means that the last element is a number between 10^34*2/3 and 10^34.

I obviously cannot have this list preallocated in memory, so something like:

```
list = [2]
while True:
    next = list[-1]*3/2
    if next > 10**34:
        break
    list.append(next)
```

Is out of the question.

I can of course simply use the above in order to iterate these integers without having them stored in a list or generated by an iterator of some sort.

But the problem is that I have nested loops, like so:

```
for i in xrange(...):
    for j in xrange(...):
        for m in xrange(...):
            for n in xrange(...):
```

So breaking this into several `while` loops would make the code pretty horrible.

Ideally, I would like to have some sort of `xrange` which generates this list of numbers "on the fly" (as `xrange`s normally do).

Comment: Actually, the list won't be very big: `math.log(10 ** 34, 1.5)` returns 193.

Comment: @timchap: Ooops!!!! So I can use a `range` too. Any idea how to generate it the pythonic way (i.e. in a single line)? Thanks

Comment: @timchap: Funny thing is, I've got [wolfram with this computation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log_%7B1.5%7D(10%5E34)) opened in my browser from before asking this question.

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in my comment, the list won't actually be very long. You could therefore initialise it as:

```
[int(2 * (1.5 ** n)) for n in range(int(math.log(10 ** 34, 1.5) - 1))]
```

However, this is actually slightly different to the example you gave, wherein you round to integer *before* generating the next number. In this case, you would have to do something iterative instead (as far as I can tell):

```
i = 2
lst = []
while i < 10 ** 34:
    lst.append(i)
    i = int(i * 1.5)
```

Comment: That `-1` up there should be `+1` IMO.

Comment: Hmm, I'm working from your requirement "The list should end at or right before 10^34". The last number in the list using `-1` is `8.599248e+33`, and the last number using `+1` is `1.934831e+34`.

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you're looking for:

```
lst = [2*1.5**i for i in range(0,192)]
```

The last term would be 2*1.5^191.

If you want them all to be integers you could say use the int() cast.

But you should note that the time/memory to do this will probably be similar to what you were doing in your example code. They are both doing similar things in the end.

If you want them all to be integers throughout the process:

```
i = 2
lst = [2]
while i < 10**34:
    lst.append(int(i*=1.5))
```

Again, this will only save a trace amount of memory/time.

Comment: This should instead be 192, since the QA requested it stop *before* 10 ^ 34. I think this is otherwise a duplicate of my answer, without the `math.log`.

Comment: That will not generate a list of **integers**! And even if you cast that to `int`, then those integers will not necessarily be the same as a list in which each integer is the floor value of the previous integer times 1.5.

Comment: i wasn't aware that was what you wanted to do. In your example code you actually didn't cast anything to an int at all, so I just followed that